# Getting "Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded" when logging in with different username

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I configured my application to allow only single session per account.
It works fine when i use JdbcDaoImpl provider.
It also works fine when i use DaoAuthenticationProvider with custom User object **extending** spring User.
But when i try to setup spring security with custom User object **implementing** UsersDetails interface i got the message above when I tried to log in using different account. I cannot figure out why.

Here is my security configuration :

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/">
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</session-management>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>      
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsServiceImplementation"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImplementation" class="com.company.service.implementation.UserServiceImpl" />
```

And my custom User object :

```
public class UserVo extends CommonVo implements UserDetails{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String enabled;

    private List<GrantedAuthority> userAuthorities;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    public void setEnabled(String enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    public List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthorities() {
        return userAuthorities;
    }
    public void setUserAuthorities(List<GrantedAuthority> userAuthorities) {
        this.userAuthorities = userAuthorities;
    }       

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return userAuthorities;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return "Y".equals(enabled) ? true : false;
    }

}
```

And this is my UserDetailsService implementation :

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @Autowired
    private UserVo userVo;

    @Override
    public int insert(UserVo userVo) {
        return userDao.insert(userVo);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<UserVo> list(UserVo userVo) {
        return (List<UserVo>) userDao.select(userVo);
    }

    public List<String> listUserRoles(UserVo userVo) {
        return (List<String>) userDao.listUserRoles(userVo);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Map select(UserVo userVo) {
        return userDao.select(userVo);
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        userVo.setUsername(username);

        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        Map result = new HashMap(userDao.select(userVo));

        List<String> userRoles = userDao.listUserRoles(userVo);
        String sRoles = StringUtils.join(userRoles, ",");
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for(String role : userRoles){
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }

        userVo.setUsername(result.get("username").toString());
        userVo.setPassword(result.get("password").toString());
        userVo.setEnabled(result.get("enabled").toString());
        userVo.setUserAuthorities(authorities);

        //return new LoginVo(result.get("username").toString(), result.get("password").toString(), AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(sRoles));
        return userVo;
    }

}
```

This works as expected if i return object that extends spring User class, in this case LoginVo.

Comment: How is your `equals` and `hashCode` implemented?

Comment: I didn't implement equals and hashCode, is that necessary here? sorry i'm fairly new at Java

Comment: Does your `CommonVo` have them implemented? And yes you need them as the default concurrency mechanism is done in memory using a `HashMap` if you have a crappy implementation of the `hashCode` and/or `equals` it won't work properly.

Comment: Thanks)), i implemented both hashCode and equals in CommonVo and UserVo as you suggested which i haven't done it before, and now it works great. I generate hashCode and equals from eclipse, I wish i can mark your comment as accepted.

Comment: Please explain what you did as an *answer* and accept it - so others can learn from you - *or* give @m-deinum the honor to transform his comment into an answer - that way he receives some reputation for it. Leaving it open without answer just annoys everyone checking if you still need help. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For concurrency control Spring Security uses a `SessionRegistry` the [default implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistryImpl.java) uses a `HashMap` to store things. For a `HashMap` to work correctly you need to have a correctly implemented `hashCode` and `equals` method. If you don't (or always return a default value) it won't work correctly.

To solve simply implement a correct `hashCode` and `equals` method in your custom object.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone faces this issue in spring boot ,this is what you have to add in your security config file,Apart From M.Deinum Answer

```
//security configuration class for implementing spring security on urls
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    //for handling user success handler
    @Autowired
    private CustomizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Override
    //this configuration is for handling user requests
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)  {
         try {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/orders").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/createrole").permitAll()
                     .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                     .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("admin")
                     .antMatchers("/agent/**").hasAuthority("agent")
                     .antMatchers("/distributor/**").hasAuthority("distributor")
                     .antMatchers("/home/**").hasAuthority("user").anyRequest()
                    .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin().successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .and().logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.done").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true) 
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
            http.sessionManagement( ).maximumSessions(1). maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
            http.sessionManagement( ).sessionFixation( ).migrateSession( )
                    .sessionAuthenticationStrategy( registerSessionAuthStr( ) );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Exception here");
        }
    }


    //this method allows static resources to be neglected by spring security
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**","/assets/**","/fonts/**","/dis/**","/vendor1/**","/mobile/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry( ) {
        SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl( );
        return sessionRegistry;
    }
    @Bean
    public RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy registerSessionAuthStr( ) {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy( sessionRegistry( ) );
    }
///Very important ,you wont login again after logout if you dont include this
    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)  {
         //BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = passwordEncoder();

    try {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Login Failed");
    }
} 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've solved my problem by following @m-deinum answer in the comment section of my original question.

What i did is generate `hashCode()` and `equals()` by right clicking eclipse -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals() in both UserVo and CommonVo.

It turns out that i have to override both method above if i have my own implementation of `UsersDetail` interface

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a normal spring application [Configured without xml] without any boot Configurations...

i overrided my hascode and equal methods in the customer.

I not able to login after 5 or 10 attempts getting msg.[Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded]

I don't have this method, how to implement in a normal application.

```
 @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
```

**in Console**-

Session is destroyed --
 Session is newly created ---
 Session is destroyed ---
 Session is newly created --
 Session is destroyed --
Session is newly created--
Session is newly created ----
Info Anonymous User.....................